# Square Connect API Does Not Populate the customer_id On Any Tender Objects

Tags: square, square-connect

I'm trying to find the attached `Customer` to a `Transaction`; and Square is not populating the customer_id on any `Tender` objects.

If I simply do a `ListTransactions`, and list all `Tenders`, none of them have any customer_id. However, I CAN simply browse the transactions in the Dashboard in the web browser, and they all have an attached customer.

I have made payments with the mobile Android App, and I add the customer to the sale before checkout ... And that transaction appears in the Dashboard and the customer IS attached! But the API does not return the customer!

Any help?

I can simply exhibit this in Postman ... Just list transactions, and none have any Tender with the customer_id ...But ALL of then DO have the customer attached in the Dashboard!

And the same is true when I use the C# Api: all `Tender` objects have no `CustomerId`.

PS: customer management IS also enabled on the mobile app ...

Comment: Is it possible that they are implicitly created customers? https://docs.connect.squareup.com/growth/customers/overview#on-instant-profiles

Comment: and are you using https://connect.squareup.com/v2/locations/{{location_id}}/transactions ?

Comment: @tristansokol No, it's not an implicitly created customer ... I have the customer in the directory before the transaction. And yes, I'm using the V2 transactions API. I don't get back a customer for ANY transactions! Even for transactions keyed from cards in the online store; and ALL of the transactions in the Dashboard DO link to a customer!

Comment: Can you share your location_id?

Comment: @tristansokol AG3X7YRHQN5QV

Comment: This appears to be a bug. We are investigating!

Comment: Ew! Ok. Well it's a blocker at the moment. I can't get a customer via a Webhook --- and I can't do any sort of query and iterate to find a customer Id anywhere!

Comment: How are you attaching the customers to the transactions?

Comment: @tristansokol I am doing that myself just in the mobile app as any sales associate would: begin a sale by selecting the customer first, and "add the customer to the sale". Add the items, and check out. (It is also happening for all sales: sales that were transacted through the Square online store, and the customer paid with a credit card: none of the returned objects from the API have any customer Id --- but every sale does have a customer attached in the Dashboard ... They all have receipts and everything associated with the customer is in the Dashboard, but the API isn't returning any Ids.)

Comment: Would it be possible for you to record a quick video of you adding the customer to the sale in POS?

Comment: We are trying to get to the bottom of this, but need to know exactly how your customers are being created, and added to the transactions

Comment: @tristansokol BOY very sorry: it appears to be working now. I promise that I had a simple test case iterate all tenders, and I had NO customer Id's ... I also ran Postman and simply searched "customer_id" in the result and got none. I just deleted my test customer, and re-created it, and I also deleted an "unnamed" customer; and also the Square Point of Sale app updated itself ... and now I see customer Id's. It's possible I did a bad diagnostic and was fooled ... I don't think so, but now it's past. I do see that it takes a minute for the customer to appear, but I have them! Thanks & sorry!